# Amazon MWS SignatureDoesNotMatch Solution

Tags: java, amazon-mws

I am getting the following error:

```
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
       −
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
</Message>
```

while  trying to make GetAuthData call following the documentation on http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/auth_token/AuthToken_GetAuthToken.html

And following http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_ClientLibraries.html#DG_OwnClientLibrary__Signatures to calculate the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was able to do to get it working:

1. Modify the calculateStringToSignV2() method in http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_ClientLibraries.html#DG_OwnClientLibrary__Signatures  to contain the trailing part of URL

   ```
       Map<String, String> sorted = new TreeMap<String, String>();
   sorted.putAll(parameters);

   // Set endpoint value
   URI endpoint = new URI(serviceUrl.toLowerCase());

   // Create flattened (String) representation
   StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
   data.append("POST\n");
   data.append(endpoint.getHost());
   data.append("\n/Sellers/2011-07-01"); //YOUR URL
   data.append("\n");

   Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> pairs =
           sorted.entrySet().iterator();
   while (pairs.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry<String, String> pair = pairs.next();
       if (pair.getValue() != null) {
           data.append( pair.getKey() + "=" + pair.getValue());
       }
       else {
           data.append( pair.getKey() + "=");
       }

       // Delimit parameters with ampersand (&)
       if (pairs.hasNext()) {
           data.append( "&");
       }
   }

   return data.toString();
   }
   ```
2. Modify the parameters.put("Timestamp", urlEncode("2013-05-02T16:00:00Z")); in the documentation http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_ClientLibraries.html#DG_OwnClientLibrary__Signatures so that timestamp parameter is in UTC and ISO-8601

so something like:

```
String dt = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z"));

parameters.put("Timestamp", urlEncode(dt));
```

P.S. I spent 5-6 hours debugging this problem and did not find any solution via Google so thought its best to put it here to save other people's time.